# How to stop asyncio cycle

Tags: python, asynchronous, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio

I am here to present a problem on which I have been struggling for a while.
Python 3.8.8 - Using Anaconda - Using Spyder.

I want to interface my Arduino Nano BLE 33 to PC through bleak library using Python. This needs to include some knowledge in AsyncIO library.

```
BUFFER_LENGHT = 13
PACKET_NUMBER = BUFFER_LENGHT*2 
address = "04:56:14:27:55:E8"
MODEL_NBR_UUID = "0000101a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" 


def process_data(dati):
    data = np.array(struct.unpack('H'*BUFFER_LENGHT,dati))
    print('_____________DATA_____________')
    print(data)
    print('_____________END______________')
    
def shutdown():
    client.disconnect()
    print('_____________INTERRUPTED_____________')    
    
    
async def main(address,loop):
    global start_timestamp, stream_queue,client
    client = BleakClient(address)
    while await client.is_connected()==False:
        try:
            await client.connect()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        start_timestamp=datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
        while True:
            dati = await client.read_gatt_char(MODEL_NBR_UUID)
            process_data(dati)
            time.sleep(2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        await client.stop_notify(MODEL_NBR_UUID) 
        await client.disconnect()
        

try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main(address, loop))
        loop.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Process interrupted")
        loop.run_until_complete(shutdown())
        loop.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

So, later than have importing all libraris, I want to read some data from Arduino using **client.read_gatt_char(MODEL_NBR_UUID)** and then unpack it.
My problem is that I am not able to stop the AsyncIO cycle. I expected to stop the code using ctrl+C, but it does not work and I was not able to understand why.

*Are there any mistakes in try-catch structure? Or maybe (more realistic) are there some unprecisions using asyncio functions?*

Could anyone help me? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are your `KeyboardInterrupt`s printed to the console? I'm guessing your exceptions get swallowed by your `try`/`except`-blocks in main, since you're spending most of you time there.

Comment: You should probably replace your `time.sleep()` with `await asyncio.sleep()`.  Not sure if that will solve your problem, but it means that while you're sleeping, other execution threads can run.

Comment: On  a side note. You appear to have picked a custom UUID value that is in the reserved range for Bluetooth SIG approved UUID’s. There is a helpful article on this topic at: https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/

Comment: @ukBaz thanks for sharing! It is just an example for now, I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword No they do not. I am actually conviced that try-catch is uncorrect. But I do not understand why. Appareantly the code keeps running in 'While True' and does not feel any others interrupt

Comment: @FrankYellin thanks! I have tried. Nothing changed :-(

Comment: I think people have pointed out the obvious problems. This is kind of difficult to really reproduce without your setup. Maybe you can post some output or exception tracebacks, if you are getting any? Spyder is adding even more complexity. BTW catching `Exception` is very unspecific and dangerous, since it can mask errors if you don't reraise them. Consider adding a `raise` to your `except`-blocks and see if you are getting any output.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword could you be more precise about raise block?
BTW, I did not catch any significant excpetions.

_____________DATA_____________
[65077   807  7887   104     7    26     0     0     0   600     0  2910
     0]
_____________END______________
_____________DATA_____________
[65064   843  7881   100     6    27     0     0     0   579     0  4980
     0]
'code' 

this is the output example I got. But, there is no way to stop the code using ctrl+C

Comment: Add the keyword `raise` after all your `print(e)`s (in the next line with the same indentation). Does your program do anything differently after you press ctrl+c or does your ouput always stop after your second data block?

Comment: I've added 'raise' block, but nothing changed. 
It does not. No outputs with ctrl+c. No the program still continues its flows printing data every 2 secs. But it does until I close the command window (it is the only way to stop the program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a Spyder-thing after all. I copied your code and after some fixing and taking out the `BleakClient` stuff it worked, so I decided to download Spyder.

Spyder apparently is based on IPython and has some peculiarities that can be unfamiliar when coming from plain Python. I'm not sure how you got to run that code in Spyder in the first place, because `run_until_complete` raises a `RuntimeError` when it's called in a cell in Spyder.

But with some modifications you can run your script in Spyder:

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from asyncio.exceptions import CancelledError

BUFFER_LENGHT = 13
PACKET_NUMBER = BUFFER_LENGHT * 2
address = "04:56:14:27:55:E8"
MODEL_NBR_UUID = "0000101a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"


def process_data(dati):
    data = dati
    print("_____________DATA_____________")
    print(data)
    print("_____________END______________")


async def shutdown():
    # client.disconnect()
    print("_____________INTERRUPTED_____________")


async def main(address):
    global start_timestamp, stream_queue, client
    # client = BleakClient(address)
    try:
        #await client.connect()
        print("connect")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        start_timestamp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
        while True:
            dati = "some data"
            process_data(dati)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
    except CancelledError: #KeyboardInterrupt is raised as CancelledError
        print("cancelled")
    finally: # your else-block was unreachable code, use finally for finalizing stuff
        print("stop notify") # your clean-up code here
        print("disconnect")

async def start(): #new main entry point
    await main(address)
```

This should work out of the box for you to play with. Just run the file with the "play" button and now you can just run your functions from the IPython interface.

```py
[2] await start()
```

will start your script. Now you should be able to stop with the "stop" button or ctrl+c inside the running cell.
This is far from perfect but I guess it should give you a starting point to reinsert your `BleakClient` logic.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your workaround. 
In Spyder it actually works! Thanks! But still, I have some concerns because I want to run it from cmd (more precisely Anaconda prompt). 
So this is the flowchart: Spyder Development --> Debug --> run by conda prompt. 

In prompt it does not work. Do you know why? 
And of course, yes! it is so far from perfect! It is just to start!

Comment: The general recipe for running this from any python >= 3.7 is `import asyncio; import my_module; asyncio.run(my_module.start())`. Again, I don't know Anaconda, but if there is no running loop yet, it should work.